# Python lxml return decimal Unicode numbers like "&#3482; &#3505;"

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

I'm trying to extract data from HTML file. (all content between two tags)
Here is my python code,

```
 page = requests.get(url)
    source = html.fromstring(page.content)

    body = ""
    for atag in source.xpath('//div[@class="lts-txt2"]'):
        body =  body + tostring(atag)
    print body
```

But it returns this `<div class="lts-txt2">&#3515;&#3540;&#3523;&#3538;&#3514;&#3535;&#3520;&#3546;`

I found these codes are Sinhala (Unicode decimal codes) - http://www.codetable.net/decimal/3530

I need to convert these as Unicode characters

Comment: `tostring()`? Why are you using that, rather than referring direct to the text node?

Comment: so what am i need to change?

Comment: `atag.text` is will have the text in its literal form, not encoded to be (X)HTML itself.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're trying to generate HTML, the encoding lxml is creating is the correct one -- any correctly implemented browser will decode those sequences, and there's no reason to change it.

Comment: after change atag -> atag.text it give me this   error                                                                  File "\get_data.py", line 58, in get_data
    body =  body + tostring(atag.text)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3165, in lxml.etree.tostring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:69414)
TypeError: Type 'unicode' cannot be serialized.

Comment: I didn't tell you to use `tostring()`. `atag.text` already **is** a string.

Comment: Oh yes, but another problem after using atag.text it mission all html tags ("<br> etc")  I need all those, tags+ text

Comment: By the way -- personally, I'd create a new root element, append all your search results to it, and then serialize that element all at once, instead of serializing each piece and concatenating them. That way you don't have any risk of duplicate declarations or such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these values to be returned as Unicode literals, then you should pass `encoding='utf-8'` to the `tostring()` call.

This will override its default behavior of escaping all non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend python3 for this kind of programs. And start your python script with `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.